# Trouble making an animated HTML title

Tags: javascript, html, animation, whitespace, title

This is my first question here. I'm trying to make my portfolio more interesting. So I tried to make a title that makes the first letter appear last. Making the effect that the title moves.
 I have done a good work with the movement, in my perspective. But the problem is that the code deletes the space between the words in the title.
 Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but i don't know what.
If this helps, I'm using Google Chrome.
Here is the code that i'm using.

```js
function titleAnim() {
  title = document.title;
  for (let i = 0; i < title.length; i = title.length) {
    let lastChar = title[i];
    let newTitle = title.slice(1);
    newTitle = newTitle + lastChar;
    document.title = newTitle;
  }
};
setInterval(titleAnim, 500);
```

Comment: If you have a loop that performs just one iteration, you don't need a loop.

Comment: I also don't see any logic here that would remove spaces.  Please create a [mcve] of the issue

Comment: I've tested it. It appears that spaces are removed.

Comment: There’s a typo in the for loop by the way, the last part should be `i ++`, or it won’t loop

Answer (score 1):

you don't need that for-loop;
and it's just fine

```js
var title = "abc defg" + " "; // add a space at the end so it won't be continous
function titleAnim() {
    let lastChar = title[0];
    let newTitle = title.slice(1);
    title = newTitle = newTitle + lastChar;
    console.log(newTitle);
};
setInterval(titleAnim, 777);
```